# copying content using dd

Tags: dd

I just copied the content of a 4 TB hard drive (NTFS partition) to a span of 2 drives (LVM) 5TB ext4 partition. I copied it using `dd if=/dev/input of=/dev/output/`. Everything work perfectly except that I ended up with a 4 TB NTFS partition in my output location.

Is there a way that I can copy the content of the filesystem and not the filesystem itself? By the way the reason I am not using rsync or cp is because I have a bunch of hardlinks and rsync was freezing. Will `dd` maintain those hardlinks?

Comment: Did you try `rsync` with `-H` option? You need that to preserve hardlinks. `-a` doesn't do it automatically.

Comment: The `dd` utility will make an exact bit for bit copy, including partition information, etc.  As Munir suggests, some different options for `rsync` will fix you up.

Comment: I have been using `rsync` but I started having problems with rsync. After 4 or more days copying files it was still not done which did not sound reasonable for the hard drives/systems that I have. After some research I learned that apparently is well documented that when you have a directory tree with tons of hard link then it gets harder to match those and it may take a really long time. That is when I decided to switch to other alternatives such as `dd`

In fact the option I was using was `rsync -H`; thanks for the suggestion; is there any way to do what I am looking for?